# Strange turning on of airplane mode when pc boot

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, airplane-mode

I have trouble with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Everytime on pc boot the airplane mode is turned on by unknown reason. I never turn it on, it is automatic. When I'm turning it off, then the bluetooth mode is turning on automatically. Then I'm turning bluetooth mode off and then everything is ok. I am doing this instruction everytime on boot (turning off the airplane mode; then turning off bluetooth mode, that was just turned on automatically after turning off airplane mode).

How can I prevent automatic turning on of airplane mode on pc boot? And how to prevent automatic turning bluetooth mode on when turning the airplane mode off?

It seems like system bug. I tried to explain this problem as possible.

P.S. When I used Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 airplane mode had never been turned on automatically when pc boot without my knowledge.

Comment: Have you installed a battery optimization app? Sometimes these apps can annoyingly turn off WIFI and Bluetooth! If you have installed a Battery Optimization app I recommend checking the settings if not, I will try to search around for a solution for you!

Comment: @JaydenW., I think not. I didn't installed optimization apps and I don't have it.

Comment: My question is still actual, I did not found any solution

Comment: I wish it worked that way for me - I have the opposite problem, since a couple of releases before 22.04, which I have just upgraded to: Airplane mode is always turned off on restart...